# Can't connect the domain between Firebase and Godaddy

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I set up the domain to Firebase Hosting with Cloud Flare. And I purchase one on Godaddy. Running well still but suddenly 404 error occurs, and it shows "Needs Setup" on Firebase. I was not doing anything!

`firebaseapp.com` is working. So I've decided to remove CloudFlare and set up like this.

*Godaddy*
[image]

*Firebase*
[image]

But it's still `Needs Setup`. How can I do solve this...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it done.
The reason is why the cloud function has been too working. I don't know why but Hosting is not working well if you used cloud function too much.